# MySQL Connector SQL Query using LIKE

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I have two sets of similar codes that gives different output. The first example does not return any output but the second example returns a output using the same search input.

First Example:

```
    sql = "SELECT accessionID, title, ISBN, publisher, publicationYear FROM Books WHERE %s LIKE %s";

    cursor.execute(sql,(col, "%" + values + "%",))
```

Second Example:

```
    sql = "SELECT accessionID, title, ISBN, publisher, publicationYear FROM Books WHERE title LIKE %s";

    cursor.execute(sql,("%" + values + "%",))
```

The codes that I am trying to code out is that WHERE is dynamic that depends on which text field user searches on. For example, if a user searches something on the title text box, it will only look into Title.

Another way I could think of is to use If conditions to hardcode, but it only works for the first If conditions and subsequent one does not work.

My question is how to make the SQL line dynamic (using first example) in the sense that I can do two %s in the SQL query line and still get the same output?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to make the SQL line dynamic in the sense that I can do two %s in the SQL query line and still get the same output?

Comment: Your first query has wrong sytax near like i.e Column name %s like

Comment: @ZahidMustafa what should it be?

Comment: What is Your column you ant to filter based on ?

Comment: the `sql` string should not contain the semicolon `;` at the end in python. You can edit strings using `f"   "` notation.  Please include full code and the error thrown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: One other thing,  in your cursor.execute() line, shouldn't it be a ```%``` and not a ```,``` between the ```sql``` variable and the tuple?